# Выгрузка из 1с УТ 10.3 на Битрикс 14.5.3

Tags: 1с, интеграция, битрикс

Добрый вечер, #братья!
Может, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой.
После выгрузки каталога товаров на битриксовый сайт (для справки: модуль обмена 4.0.0.6) в битрикс-каталоге идет разделение - товары отдельно, категории и подкатегории отдельно. Сам битрикс чистый, то есть никаких кастомных модулей по интеграции и т.д. не присутствует. К сожалению, всего 2-ю неделю знакомлюсь со 1С... и как бы "удачно". 
Чтоб упростить понимание проблемы, картиночки ниже по ссылке:
[Картинка 1](http://dktests.1gb.ru/1%D1%81-trouble-1.jpg)
[Картинка 2](http://dktests.1gb.ru/1%D1%81-trouble-2.jpg)

Comment: Ну, что могу пожелать - терпения разбираться в этих дебрях))))

А если по вопросу, то сдается мне, что признак "Товар" определенный в 1С УТ для того, чтоб отличать товар от услуги  - читается вашим Битриксом как категория. Куда-то туда копайте.

Comment: @Ale_x, как тепло ты пишешь о форумчанах))), братья даже)). Удачи тебе в этом вопросе). Думаю, кто давно работал с этим, помогут тебе).

Comment: не совсем понял коммент в мою строну?

Comment: Фишка в том, что такой косяк появляется при выгрузке на чистую установку Б..... Если изначально поставить какой нибудь аля магаз из маркетплейса, такой ерунды нет...

А что с этим уже давно не работают?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось гораздо проще.
Админ часть -> Настройки -> Настройки модулей -> Информационные блоки
поставить галочку на против - "Совместный просмотр разделов и элементов"